# How do I get Python to recognize that it is running on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: rpi.gpio

I just purchased a Pi 2, and every time I use `import RPi.GPIO` in Python it returns an error that says `RPi.GPIO` can only be run on a Raspberry Pi, but I am running it on a Pi.  I tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, but it still doesn't recognize the Pi.  What can I do about this?

Comment: Is this a fresh install or did you copy the SD card from another Pi.  Did you install RPi.GPIO yourself or did you use a pre-installed version?

Comment: Did you custom compile a kernel? What version of RPI.GPIOS are you running. See this  http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/84/ for more info. I believe this will fix the problem  sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio

Answer (score 1):

The library had to be updated for raspberry 2 boards - I believe it is documented in "issue 95" which is listed on site : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO see also this forum post on raspberry site : http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=99281